# AngularJs Run block $stateChangeStart not being fired

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My AngularJs run block does not execute the handler function when the application changes routes, at least that is what I think. I tried putting a simple console log to test and it does not log anything. The final objective is to be a route interceptor checking if the route needs authentication.

Link for github repository https://github.com/guilinden/authenticatedCRUD

```
(function(){
    angular
    .module('app')
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
        var requireLogin = toState.data.requireLogin;

        if(requireLogin){
            event.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/home');
        }

      });
   });    
})();
```

Comment: consider a fix: `.module('app', [])`

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: The question should contain http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , where M stands for minimal. `run` definitely should be executed, otherwise you would get an error in the console.

Comment: Please delete comments that are no longer valid or needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### $stateChange* events are deprecated

The `$stateChange*` events are deprecated in 1.0. They are replaced with the `$transitions.on*` transition hooks.

However, they can be re-enabled for backwards compatibility by including `stateEvents.js` and depending on the `'ui.router.state.events'` angular module.

```
<script src="stateEvents.js">
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.router.state.events']);
```

See [UI-router Issue #2720 - $stateChangeStart not being fired on v1.0](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2720)

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There should be a **`app not defined`** error in your console. You are missing empty dependencies

```
 angular
    .module('app',[])
```

also change it as, $location as a dependency to run,

```
  .run(function ($rootScope,$location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
```

Comment: The module is definied in another file, this part is working. The repo is available at https://github.com/guilinden/authenticatedCRUD

Comment: Did not work. If I add a console log before the handler function it logs, but inside it does not. The $rootScope.$on function is not being executed

Comment: it should, create a plunker to demonstrate your isue